# c++ getSize() method returning strange value

Tags: c++

I'm creating cpScalar.hpp and cpVector.hpp files, and I'm having error calling getSize() method of cpVector. Below is my code.

Removing v2 in main changes output of v1 to 4, but having v2 leads to weird output. I tried changing return this->size to return arr.size(), but it gives similar output.

Can someone tell me why this happens, how to fix it, or give me a directive link to a page that tells me about this? I don't know what this kind of problem is called so I cannot even search for a similar problem.

Thanks.

```
//cpVector.hpp
private:
    vector<cpScalar> arr;
    unsigned int size;

public:
    cpVector(cpScalar sarr[], unsigned int size2){ // this constructor is fixed
        arr.resize(size2);
        this->size = size2;
        for (int i =0; i<size2; i++){
            arr[i] = sarr[i];
        }
    };
unsigned int getSize(){
        return this->size;
    };

and at main:

int main()
{
    cpScalar s_arr[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        s_arr[i] = cpScalar(i+1); //1, 2, 3, 4
    }
    cpVector v1(s_arr, 4);

    cpScalar s_arr2[4];
    for(int i = 4; i < 8; i++){
        s_arr2[i] = cpScalar(i+1); //5,6,7,8
    }
    cpVector v2(s_arr2, 4);
    cout << v1.getSize() <<  endl; // prints 1097313485
    cout << v2.getSize() << endl; // prints 4
}
```

The output is :

1097313485\n
4

and output after removing v2 is just 4

Comment: `s_arr2[i] = cpScalar(i+1);` causes segmentation fault with i = 4,5,6,7 because `s_arr2` is defined with size 4. This line should be rewritten, for instance, like `s_arr2[i-4] = cpScalar(i+1);`.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks!